# NSString with copy property

Tags: objective-c

in Class PC i have

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * imageURL;
```

and in dealloc of PC i have `[imageURL release];` this should never, ever cause a crash

in another class i call

```
pc.imageURL = url;
```

**i want to ask if iam doning this ok, because my app has weird crashes**

previously i always done

```
pc.imageURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:url];
```

thank you

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to find out *why* and *where* it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is correct. However, what you did before was wrong, because

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithString:url];
```

retains the new string, but it gets never released.

I think you've built in a `release` you don't need, because you tried to avoid a memory leak before.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i dont understand the meaning of last sentence "I think you've built in a release you don't need, because you tried to avoid a memory leak before." and i thought that if i do [[NSString alloc] initWithString:url], than release is automaticly called on the default content

Comment: [[NString alloc] initWithString:url] doesn't autorelease. [NSString stringWithString:url] does autorelease. If you alloc it, you own it and have to release it.

Comment: @Peter: Basically Terry said it already. I believe you've added an unnecessary `-release` which worked because you erroneously retained your string by doing `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:url];`. You have to figure out where you're releasing the string where you shouldn't.